# How to have attribute inheritance for Vue component slots?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I'm writing a Vue component, which accepts 2 slots:

```
<template>
  <div class="Component">
    <div class="Component-Label">
      <slot
        name="label"
        class="Component-LabelInner"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="Component-Input">
      <slot
        name="input"
        class="Component-InputInner"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.Component { ... }

.Component-Label { ... }

.Component-LabelInner { ... }

.Component-Input { ... }

.Component-InputInner { width: 100%; ... }
</style>
```

For layout purposes, I absolutely need to apply some styles to the `<slot>` elements - the ones with `Component-LabelInner` and `Component-InputInner` classes.

(To be precise I need to apply a rule `width: 100%` to the `Component-InputInner`, as usually I'll pass there `<input>` element and I want everything I pass there to stretch to the container.)

The problem is that after `<slot>` elements get replaced by the content provided to the slots, `class` attribute isn't inherited (it seems no attributes are inherited on slots) and CSS selectors for `.Component-LabelInner` and `.Component-InputInner` don't work.

Can you somehow add CSS classes to the element that `<slot>` gets replaced with?

Comment: `<div class="Component"` missing a `>`

Comment: True ;). Corrected.

Comment: Instead of assigning `class="bla"` to the `<slot>`, have you tried to add that class to the including Element reference instead? Also, are you sure you need `width: 100%` - I mean are you sure it's not related to the `display` property value being not `block` or sort of?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Of course I could do that, but that would break the idea of component isolation - I would have to remember to add that class outside the component, every time I use the component. I'm looking for a clean solution to have everything encapsulated inside the component.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I need `width: 100%`, because usually I'm passing `<input>` to the `input` slot. `<input>`s don't have `display: block` by default, so they don't resize to fit the container unless you specifically tell them to (which I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not bind class to `slot` tag. There are some solutions to handle this case:

1. With Vue `mounted` hook (it works but looks as bad practice):

```js
Vue.component("slots-comp", {
  template: "#slotsCompTemplate",
  mounted() {
    // each slot is an array, because you can pass a set of nodes wrap them with template tag
    // I use only first VNode for example
    this.$slots.one && this.$slots.one[0].elm.classList.add("one");
    this.$slots.two && this.$slots.two[0].elm.classList.add("two");
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {}
})
```

```css
.one {
  color: red
}

.two {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <slots-comp>
     <div slot="one">One</div>
     <div slot="two">Two</div>
   </slots-comp>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="slotsCompTemplate">
  <div>
    <slot name="one"></slot>
    <slot name="two"></slot>
  </div>
</script>
```

2. Pass neccessary classes as props to scoped slot(it is not fully encapsulated solution):

```js
Vue.component("slots-comp", {
  template: "#slotsCompTemplate",
  data() {
   return {
      classes: {
       one: ["one"],
        two: ["two"]
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {}
})
```

```css
.one {
  color: red
}

.two {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <slots-comp>
     <div slot-scope="props" :class="props.classes.one" slot="one">One</div>
     <div slot-scope="props" :class="props.classes.two" slot="two">Two</div>
   </slots-comp>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="slotsCompTemplate">
  <div>
    <slot :classes="classes" name="one"></slot>
    <slot :classes="classes" name="two"></slot>
  </div>
</script>
```

3. Add changes to CSS to apply styles on all internal elements:

   ```
   .Component-Input > * 
   {
       /* my rules for child elements */
   }

   .Component-Label> * 
   {
       /* my rules for child elements */
   }
   ```

   Or add wrapper element for slots with classes `Component-InputInner` etc. and add similar styles for them.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, especially for multiple solutions. I've used solution #1 (even came up with it myself yesterday). #2 as you said doesn't encapsulate the solution inside the component (you have to remember to apply attributes in outer templates, when you use the component). #3 keeps it inside the component, but universal selector is something I almost totally avoid, because it's very prone to leaking styles. Adding wrapper you proposed in #3 won't work - I have to apply styles directly on the element I have inside the slot. #1 is maybe not the most elegant, but functionally doesn't have any drawbacks.